# How to measure a hex or jam nut?

Tags: electrical, repair, tools

I need a jam/hex nut for the mic input for the below speaker. On the picture the connector have been pushed in because the nut is missing.

**Question**

- It should be a 3/8-32 jam nut, but how can I verify this?
- How do I measure the size of the current?

[image]

Comment: The easiest way would be to take one of the others off and take it to the store with you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about repairing stereo equipment, not home improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first check that the missing hex nut is the same size as nut on one of the two output jacks. This can be done by removing one and seeing if it fits on the jack with the missing nut. This temporarily removed nut can be used as a sample for comparison when buying a new nut.

Nuts of this style should be readily available via online retailers such as Digikey or Mouser. If you go to a retail store it may be harder to find the nuts as an individual purchase item. You may find yourself purchasing a whole replacement jack and stealing the nut from it to replace the missing one on your speaker. Some of the really good (often older) hardware stores will have specialty drawers with various odd ball fasteners and nuts. You could get lucky and find your replacement nut there.

http://www.mouser.com/catalog/catalogusd/647/2952.pdf